# API call every day at a specific time in java?

Tags: java, scheduler

I want to create a scheduler in java which makes an API calls every day at a specific time and saves the content in a text file. One option would be to do something like this. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/. But then is there any other way to do that in java? I am looking for the most efficient approach. Any suggestions.

```
@Component
    class WelcomeService {

        public String retrieveWelcomeMessage() {
            //Complex Method
             String msgType="Hello World";
             RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
           String consumeJSONString = restTemplate.getForObject("https://ubasocials.ubagroup.com/geo-locationservice/odata/ATMs", String.class);
           writetexttofile(consumeJSONString);

          /* Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Quote r = gson.fromJson(consumeJSONString, Quote.class);
            msgType=r.getValue().getQuote();*/
            return msgType;
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A `ScheduledTask` is exactly doing what you want, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: What do you mean by most efficient? It's once a day... does it really matter?

Comment: Do you mean in "pure" java or are you using spring ?

Comment: Introducing yourself to **time** in programming is like introducing yourself to **event driven** programming which gets close to introducing yourself to **multithreading** and a whole world that comes with it, now try imagining what happens when **time** will call **retrieveWelcomeMessage() during the time** when **writetexttofile(consumeJSONString)** was busy writing stuff, speaking of **efficiency** as you mentioned :)

Comment: Have you already seen [Quartz Job Scheduling](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring boot: 
1. Add @EnableScheduling annotation to the main classes shown below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MySchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySchedulerApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

2. add a scheduler class

````
@Component
public class JobScheduler {
        @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * ?")
        public void cronJobSch() {
            //to do
        }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Make your WelcomeService runnable, then pass it into an instance of the ScheduledExecutorService.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService sheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
sheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableWelcomeService, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use any frameworks like spring. You can use [windows task scheduler to schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) your java code.

Step1: Package your java code as a runnable jar.

Step2: Create a batch file that runs the jar.

Step3: Use batch file in windows tash scheduler.